# br.financas.yahoo Internal Server Error 500

Tags: csv, yahoo-finance, currency-exchange-rates

Since Tomorrow, Yahoo Finance link for get currency exchanges is not working anymore.

The response for URL : http://br.financas.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=BRLUSD=X&f=sl1d1t1ba&e=.csv

The network inspect show :

```
    Internal Server Error 500.
```

And the Reponse HTML is :

```
  <!-- myproperty:myservice-BR:1:Failure - 404 -->
  <!-- fe232.global.media.bf1.yahoo.com uncompressed/chunked Fri Feb 14 15:58:58 UTC 2014 -->
  <!-- ncache9.global.media.bf1.yahoo.com uncompressed/chunked Fri Feb 14 15:58:58 UTC 2014 -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Apparently the Yahoo Team installed service in other URI.

Is was changed to :

```
http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=BRLUSD=X&f=sl1d1t1ba&e=.csv
```

Works now!